# adding additional data to array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I build up an array like so from a SimpleXML Object like so

```
$currentXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($getCurrentXML);
$leadArray = array();

foreach($currentXML->Job->Employee as $object) {
    $dataArray[] = array(
        'ID' => (string)$object->ID,
        'Date Identified' => $dateIdentified,
        'Name' => (string)$object->Name,
        'Owner' => (string)$object->Owner->Name,
        'Value' => (string)$object->EstimatedValue
    );
}
```

If I output the data for the above, I get something like this which is perfect

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "ID" => "1230279"
    "Date Identified" => "19/04/2016"
    "Name" => "Some Name"
    "Owner" => "Some Owner"
    "Value" => "Some Value"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▶]
  2 => array:7 [▶]
  3 => array:7 [▶]
  4 => array:7 [▶]
  5 => array:7 [▶]
  6 => array:7 [▶]
  7 => array:7 [▶]
]
```

Now within the above foreach loop, I need to use $object->ID to query another API.  SO I have

```
foreach($currentXML->Job->Employee as $object) {
    $dataArray[] = array(
        'ID' => (string)$object->ID,
        'Date Identified' => $dateIdentified,
        'Name' => (string)$object->Name,
        'Owner' => (string)$object->Owner->Name,
        'Value' => (string)$object->EstimatedValue
    );

    $customField = Helper::getCustomFields((string)$object->ID);
    $currentFieldsXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($customField);
}
```

Now if I output currentFieldsXML, sometimes I am returned and empty SimpleXMLElement Object, sometimes it contains data.
What I am trying to do is push the data into the array alongside its other data.  So I have this

```
foreach($currentXML->Job->Employee as $object) {
    $dataArray[] = array(
        'ID' => (string)$object->ID,
        'Date Identified' => $dateIdentified,
        'Name' => (string)$object->Name,
        'Owner' => (string)$object->Owner->Name,
        'Value' => (string)$object->EstimatedValue
    );

    $customField = Helper::getCustomFields((string)$object->ID);
    $currentFieldsXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($customField);

    if(!empty($currentFieldsXML->CustomFields)) {
        foreach($currentFieldsXML->CustomFields as $custom) {
            array_push($dataArray, (string)$custom->CustomField->ID);
            array_push($dataArray, (string)$custom->CustomField->Name);
            array_push($dataArray, (string)$custom->CustomField->Text);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the output is something like this

```
array:23 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▶]
  1 => array:7 [▶]
  2 => "122156"
  3 => "Some Data"
  4 => "Some more Data"
  5 => array:7 [▶]
  6 => "122156"
  7 => "Date"
  8 => "20 April"
]
```

So element 0 has no custom fields associated with it.  Element 1 does have data, but it is displaying as element 2, 3 and 4.  In essence, the above
should look something like this

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▶]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "ID" => "1230279"
    "Date Identified" => "19/04/2016"
    "Name" => "Some Name"
    "Owner" => "Some Owner"
    "Value" => "Some Value"
    array:3 [
      1 => "122156"
      2 => "Some Data"
      3 => "Some more Data"
    ]
  ]
  ...
]
```

So how can I add the data I am returned into its appropiate array as shown above?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$iterator=0;
foreach($currentXML->Job->Employee as $object) {
    $dataArray[$iterator] = array(
        'ID' => (string)$object->ID,
        'Date Identified' => $dateIdentified,
        'Name' => (string)$object->Name,
        'Owner' => (string)$object->Owner->Name,
        'Value' => (string)$object->EstimatedValue
     );

     $customField = Helper::getCustomFields((string)$object->ID);
     $currentFieldsXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($customField);

     if(!empty($currentFieldsXML->CustomFields)) {
         $seconditerator=0;
         foreach($currentFieldsXML->CustomFields as $custom) {
            $dataArray[$iterator][$custom->CustomField->ID][$seconditerator]=(string)$custom->CustomField->ID;
            $dataArray[$iterator][$custom->CustomField->ID][$seconditerator]=(string)$custom->CustomField->Name;
            $dataArray[$iterator][$custom->CustomField->ID][$seconditerator]=(string)$custom->CustomField->Text;
            $seconditerator++;
         }
     }
     $iterator++;
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I made a mistake on what element I was checking.  Thanks, your answer works perfectly.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your amendments to the question it will now work according to your requirements